# jquery check if this is equal to 0,1 or 2

Tags: jquery, show-hide

first sorry for my bad English,
I'm having a small problem with `.eq()` jQuety function.
I have the follow HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to check on `.click` if this is the first li the second li or the third li.
if it is the first or the second I want to `.hide` a div and if it is the third li I want to `.show` it.

BTW, I know I can use `:not` function but it does not support IE8 so I can't you it.

Thanks, Amit

EDIT: thank, I ended up going this:

```
if($(this).is(':nth-child(3)') == true) {
     $("#redB .bundleInfo p").show();
}else {
     $("#redB .bundleInfo p").hide();
};
```

Comment: Post the javsacript your currently using.

Comment: `if($(this).eq() == 0/1/2){ //code } else { //code }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
  $('li').click(function(){

     switch($(this).index()){
      case 0:
        alert("its 0");
        break;
      case 1:
        alert("its 1");
        break;
      case 2:
        alert("its 2");
        break;

      default:
        alert("other")
        break;

      }

})
```

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` method:

```
var $li = $('ul li');

$li.click(function(){
   $('div').toggle( $li.index(this) > 1 );
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qnNeN/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $("ul li").each(function(){

   $(this).click(function(){

      if (index >= 0 && index <= 1) {
       // here someting
        } else {
       // here someting
       }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current HTML you could do something like this :

```
$("li").bind("click", function(){
    var myLiElems= $("li");
    var curIdx = myLiElems.index($(this));

    if (2 == curIdx) {
        // show my div
    } else {
        // hide my div
    }
});
```

More info on the index() function of jQuery here : http://api.jquery.com/index/

Given your current javascript you need to check the documentation of the eq() function here : http://api.jquery.com/eq/ it is not working as you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$(this).index()` to get the clicked li's position (0-indexed) in the ul.

***[The live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/5NKHx/1/)***

```
​$('ul > li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    if (index >= 0 && index <= 1) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do someting else
    }
});​
```